# How to ensure a fried egg's yolk doesn't break?

Tags: eggs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I flip an egg when preparing it “over easy”?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/710/how-do-i-flip-an-egg-when-preparing-it-over-easy)
>   [Perfect Fried Egg](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/6402/perfect-fried-egg)

I wanna to cook a medium fried egg, but every time I try to turn the egg over, I just break the egg's yolk. Is there any technique I can use to keep the yolk intact when I flip it?